# Update value from a property of a referenced child item in DataGridView

Tags: xaml, devexpress, maui

I'm using DevExpress in my MAUI app. In one of the pages I've got a `DataGridView` to display a list of items. Each item contains a property called `MoveQuantity` which I show for each item in the `DataGridView`. Some code in the page's ViewModel modifies this property though and the value is not updated in the GUI, even though I call `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Items))`.

```
<dxg:DataGridView.Columns>
    <dxg:TextColumn Row="0" Column="0" FieldName="DocumentItemId" SortOrder="Ascending" Caption="Code" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="20" />
    <dxg:TextColumn Row="0" Column="1" FieldName="MoveQuantity" HorizontalContentAlignment="End" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
    <dxg:TextColumn Row="0" Column="2" FieldName="DocumentItemDirection" FontColor="{StaticResource NormalHeaderText}"/>
</dxg:DataGridView.Columns>
```

How can I update the value in the GUI?